# Authenticatioin of user in wp8 app using google login

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, google-authenticator

I want to authenticate a user from my wp8 app using users google login credentials. So that I can get profile info of user. I found two articles in web with source code. But I was unable to get what I want.

First code I've found in this [Link](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/google-services/how-to-add-google-login-using-oauth-2-0-in-windows-phone-8-app/). But after getting authentication code it didn't have any code to get profile. May be I could not understand.

Second code I've found in this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321291/Google-OAuth-on-Windows-Phone). It was following mvvm pattern, so I was totally blank to understand this code.

If anyone have used it properly, please help me. What actually I want that after getting client id and client secret what to do in app to get user's profile info. Helps are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

{

```
base.OnNavigatedTo(e);



IDictionary<string, string> parameters = this.NavigationContext.QueryString;



string authEndpoint = parameters["authEndpoint"];

string clientId = parameters["clientId"];

string scope = parameters["scope"];



string uri = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3}",

    authEndpoint,

    clientId,

    "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",

    scope);



webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
```

}

```
private async void LayoutRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

{

```
if(!App.loggedin)

{

    OAuthAuthorization authorization = new OAuthAuthorization(

    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",

    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

    TokenPair tokenPair = await authorization.Authorize(

        "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",

        "CLIENT_SECRET",

        new string[] { GoogleScopes.UserinfoEmail });



    // Request a new access token using the refresh token (when the access token was expired)

    TokenPair refreshTokenPair = await authorization.RefreshAccessToken(

        "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",

        "CLIENT_SECRET",

        tokenPair.RefreshToken);

}
```

}

what to do after getting access token?

Comment: Post your current code and point out which parts are not working as expected.

Comment: @Jordan Edited question. Please help

Comment: Looks like the user has to give concent to you getting their profile info. Did you get that far?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that allows you to view the profile details:

```
private void LoadProfile(string access_token)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("loading profile");

    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://www.googleapis.com");
    client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(access_token);
    var request = new RestRequest("/oauth2/v1/userinfo", Method.GET);
    client.ExecuteAsync<Profile>(request, ProfileLoaded);
}
private void ProfileLoaded(IRestResponse<Profile> response)
{
    Profile = response.Data;
}
```

Just pass in the access_token you got from your prior code and the data should be contained in `response.Data`

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Finally got profile info. Actually I was getting confused.

Comment: yo (y).....If u can provide me any window phone project.. pawan.tiwari93@gmail.com